# Изменение цвета подписи Spinner

Tags: android, kotlin

Делаю приложение для изменения цвета приложения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как изменить цвет подписи у `Spinner` программно, т.к. в зависимости от цвета должен меняться и цвет текста. Хотел через `setTextColor` как у кнопок, но у `Spinner` нет такого метода

Answer (score 2):

Подключите к вашему `Spinner` вот такой адаптер:

```
public class MySpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context ctx;
    List<String> objects;

    MySpinnerAdapter(Context context, String[] objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_spinner, objects);
        ctx = context;
        this.objects = Arrays.asList(objects);
    }

    //для показа в меню
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    //для показа в закрытом виде
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    View getCustomView(int position, View convertView,
                       ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = View.inflate(ctx, R.layout.item_spinner, null);

        ... ваша логика изменения цвета:
        if () {
            convertView.setBackground(нужный цвет);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }
}
```

И в нем пропишите логику смены цвета.

В качестве `R.layout.item_spinner` используйте или свой лэйаут или возьмите у андроида (который обычно используется в обычном адаптере).